# Cannot resolve srp-library in app.module.ts

Tags: angular

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeModule } from '@modules/home/home.module';
import { DemoMaterialModule } from '@shared/material-module';
import { PopupStore } from '@stores/index';

import { SrpLibraryModule } from 'srp-library';
import { AlertDemoComponent } from '@components/alert-demo/alert-demo.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AlertDemoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    HomeModule,
    SrpLibraryModule

  ],
  providers: [
    MediaMatcher,
    PopupStore
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So this is app.module.ts page.

In below image I have posted the error which showing unable to resolve alert component in app.module.

When I run `ng serve` Im getting following error, can any one help me to resolve this.

[image: Error message]

Comment: HAve you done `npm install` after adding this in package.json ?

Comment: Can you show code of `AlertDemoComponent `

Answer (score 0):

Delete node modules folder and run npm install again.
If again the error will come then share your component code.